# Story about a book/writing invading our reality

Tags: story-identification

I was assigned to read this short story in a college science fiction course around 2000. All I remember is that the plot involved a book(?) or a series of writings about an ancient or possible alternate-universe culture, that people became obsessed with, to the point where they began adopting the customs, language, etc. of this alien culture--until, gradually, it's as if Earth has been replaced by that culture, and that other world is effectively brought into existence. No idea of title, author, or year it was written.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I read. Great to revisit it after all these years.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Tlön, Uqbar, Orbis Tertius" is a short story by the 20th-century Argentinian writer Jorge Luis Borges. The story was first published in Spanish in Argentina in May 1940. The first English-language translation of the story was published in 1961.

The synopsis of the story is as follows:

> In a fictional timeline of 1940 Borges and his friend and
> collaborator, Adolfo Bioy Casares, find a encyclopedia which is an
> American clone of the 1902 edition of Encyclopædia Britannica with
> mysterious discrepancies between their reprints.
>
> In one of those reprints there are allusions to a mysterious country
> called Uqbar situated in a world called Tlön. These allusions do not
> appear in any other reprint or in any other encyclopedia.
>
> Later, Borges comes in possession of a volume of an English-language
> encyclopedia entirely devoted to Tlön. The people of the imaginary
> Tlön hold an extreme form of Berkeley's subjective idealism, denying
> the reality of the world.
>
> By 1941, the world and the narrator have learned, through the
> emergence of a letter, that a "benevolent secret society" was formed
> in the 17th century. Its main purpose was to create a country: Uqbar.
>
> The American "eccentric" millionaire Ezra Buckley, one of the members
> of the restored sect, finds (in the late 19th Century) its undertaking
> too modest, proposing that their creation be of an entire world
> instead of just a country. He also adds that an entire encyclopedia
> about this world—named Tlön—must be written.
>
> By 1942, Tlönian objects began to inexplicably appear in the real
> world.
>
> By 1944, all forty volumes of the First Encyclopedia of Tlön have been
> discovered and published in a library in Memphis. The material becomes
> accessible worldwide and immensely influential on Earth's culture,
> science and languages. By the time Borges concludes the story,
> presumably in 1947, the world is gradually becoming Tlön.

[Tlön, Uqbar, Orbis Tertius - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tl%C3%B6n,_Uqbar,_Orbis_Tertius)

Comment: *The world will be Tlön.*